# Add a column before username in the users profile table

Tags: users, screen-columns

I want to reorder the Company column to be the first column in the table, the code is working fine but it's position is the last one. How can I get it to be in the first before the username?

```
function add_company_column($defaults) {
    $defaults['company'] = __('Company');
    return $defaults;
}

function view_company_column($value, $column_name, $id) {
    if ($column_name == 'company') {
        global $wpdb;
        $companyID = get_usermeta($id, 'company');
        $company = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT com_name FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "companies WHERE com_id = " . $companyID);
        return $company->com_name;
    }
}

add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'add_company_column', 15, 1);
add_action('manage_users_custom_column', 'view_company_column', 15, 3);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it by unsetting `$defaults` and reconstructing it after adding the company

```
function add_company_column($defaults) {
    unset($defaults);
    $defaults['company'] = __('Company');
    $defaults['username'] = __('username');
    $defaults['name'] = __('Name');
    $defaults['email'] = __('Email');
    return $defaults;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to unset all the columns and build the columns all-together. What you can do is split the default columns array after the 1st column, then merge the new custom column array with the other 2 arrays. Have a look at the following code.

```
function add_company_column( $defaults ) {
    $new_columns = array();

    $columns_1 = array_slice( $defaults, 0, 1 );
    $columns_2 = array_slice( $defaults, 1 );

    $new_columns = $columns_1 + array( 'company' => __('Company') ) + $columns_2;
    return $new_columns;
}
```

With the above code, the `company` column will be shown before `username` column.

You can have a look at a complete article on this including sortable custom column on **[Webtechideas](http://www.webtechideas.com/how-to-add-sortable-custom-column-on-users-listing-screen-in-wordpress/)**.